# How to remove IT policy from previous employer on Windows Vista?

Tags: laptop, windows-vista, bios, passwords, administrator

I have a laptop from my previous employer with an IT policy (I believe that's the correct term :P) on it, so I can't install any new software since I need an administrator password, which I don't have. Using the `Offline Windows Password and Registry Editor` won't work either since they removed the `Boot to CD` and `Boot to USB` options from the BIOS. You can apparently boot to an ISO with UNetBootin, but of course I can't use that since I can't install anything. Is it possible to boot over Ethernet? I saw an option for this in the BIOS.
After this is done I would like to format the hard drive and do a fresh install of Windows 7. Note that I use Windows Vista Business.
Thanks!

**UPDATE** The BIOS update is, as expected, an .exe, so I can't do that. Going to try the CMOS battery option

Comment: How are you in this position?

Comment: @Raystafarian My father's boss let him keep an old work laptop when he left his company

Comment: Simplest solution update bios this should reset it, if not, remove the CMOS battery but that isn't always a solution

Comment: @Ramhound thanks I'll try that, but I assume I'll just find I need the admin account again?

Comment: If you can reset the BIOS settings that will allow you to use software required to add your own local accounts and delete the domain profiles that exist on the system.

Comment: @Ramhound I just did a "reset to factory defaults", didn't work. I'm about to try update it and if all else fails I'll remove the CMOS battery

Comment: **UPDATE** The BIOS update is, as expected, an .exe, so I can't do that. Going to do the CMOS battery option

Comment: Was this computer built by an OEM because its unusual it doesn't have the options you need because those are still required even in an Enterprise environment.

Comment: @Ramhound originally built by OEM, but when the HDD died the IT department replaced it, not sure if BIOS was modified somehow at that time

Comment: You can always install an operating system like Linux which is more forgiving about the system configuration, on another pc, then install the hdd in order to apply the firmware.  You can also use Windows if you SysPrep it before hand.

Comment: @Ramhound ik Linux is awesome :3 Luckily I have reached the Win7 installer, but it still hasn't finished yet. Thanks though, and if this works please post that as an answer and I'll accept it (I'll let you know)

Comment: It's working like a charm. Cheers!

Comment: Please do not update your question with "Solved" either post a answer and accept it or delete the question.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Posted, and I'll have to accept it tomorrow